# petsc4py mapping from _DMDA_Vec_array to Vec for use in TS

Tags: python, petsc

I have initialized `ts = PETSc.TS().create()` and attempt to solve with some initial distribution with `ts.setSolution(u)` and get a type error.

It seems as though it would like the type `Vec` but is getting passed as a `_DMDA_Vec_array`.

The setup goes as follows:

1. create `dmda = PETSc.DMDA().create(<...>)`
2. create a global vector `x = dmda.createGlobalVec()`
3. get our IC vector: `ic = dmda.getVecArray(x)`
4. fill IC vector
5. attempt `ts.setSolution(ic)` but it doesn't like that `ic` is a `_DMDA_Vec_array`object

So far I have found two things:

1. `ic = dmda.getVecArray(x)` is doing what it is supposed to do--create a `_DMDA_Vec_array` object
2. in regular PETSc, the equivalent would be to use the function `DMDAVecGetArray()` and then once you've filled the values, you run the function `DMDAVecRestoreArray()` to convert the `_DMDA_Vec_array` object back to a usable `Vec` object for `ts`.

What is the equivalent protocol/workflow in Python for `_DMDA_Vec_array` to `Vec` type?